# Python to count the consecutive values based on the column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe and need to get a count of consecutive for each row based on the `delay_category1` and `delay_category2` columns . These two represents the time bucket in seconds .

**Dataframe**

```
Id| Name| Delay_category1| Delay_category2 |    
1| xyz1 | [0-10]         |   [11-20]       |    
2| xyz2 | [0-10]         |   [11-20]       |    
3| xyz3 | [0-10]         |   [11-20]       |    
4| xyz4 | [30-60]        |   [0-10]        |
```

**Expected Output**

```
Id| Name| Delay_Category1| Delay_category2 | Consecutive_Count |    
1 | xyz1| [0-10]         |   [11-20]       |         3         |    
2 | xyz2| [0-10]         |   [11-20]       |         2         |    
3 | xyz3| [0-10]         |   [11-20]       |         1         |    
4 | xyz4| [30-60]        |    [0-10]       |         1         |
```

Comment: This is not a question

Comment: question is not clear to me  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a more instructive example, I added 2 more rows, with both
*Delay_category* like in the first row:

```
   Id  Name Delay_category1 Delay_category2
0   1  xyz1          [0-10]         [11-20]
1   2  xyz2          [0-10]         [11-20]
2   3  xyz3          [0-10]         [11-20]
3   4  xyz4         [30-60]          [0-10]
4   5  xyz5          [0-10]         [11-20]
5   6  xyz6          [0-10]         [11-20]
```

Note that these 2 additional rows should actually be treated as **another**
(third) group, instead of concatenated with the initial group.

To create the new column, run:

```
df['Consecutive_Count'] = df.groupby(
    (df.Delay_category1.ne(df.Delay_category1.shift()) &
    df.Delay_category2.ne(df.Delay_category2.shift())).cumsum())\
    .cumcount(ascending=False) + 1
```

The result is:

```
   Id  Name Delay_category1 Delay_category2  Consecutive_Count
0   1  xyz1          [0-10]         [11-20]                  3
1   2  xyz2          [0-10]         [11-20]                  2
2   3  xyz3          [0-10]         [11-20]                  1
3   4  xyz4         [30-60]          [0-10]                  1
4   5  xyz5          [0-10]         [11-20]                  2
5   6  xyz6          [0-10]         [11-20]                  1
```

Note that the other solution would **concatenate** all rows with both
*Delay_category* equal to *[0-10]* and *[11-20]*, what in my opinion is
**not** what you want.

The other solution gives proper result only if the input DataFrame contains
no such "repeated" groups.

Comment: Thank you for the solution .The above solution is what I expected . But I see that when i change the values of delay category column with other buckets i am not getting the desired output .

Comment: The output by changing the delay category column values  
Output:
Delay_category1 Delay_category2 Consecutive_Count

[11-30] [0-10] 4
[11-30] [0-10] 3
[11-30] [0-10] 2
[30-60] [0-10] 1
[0-10] [11-30] 2
[0-10] [11-30] 1
[31-60] [0-10] 7
[11-30] [0-10] 6
[11-30] [0-10] 5
[11-30] [0-10] 4
[11-30] [0-10] 3
[11-30] [0-10] 2
[11-30] [0-10] 1

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution . I concatenated delay category columns and got the output .

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to count the number of occurrences of the same pair of values from the 2 columns `delay_category1` and `delay_category2` from current row down. That is, how many rows from this row down (including current row) have the same pair of values for the 2 columns.

In this case, you can use [`GroupBy.cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), as follows:

```
df['Consecutive_Count'] = df.groupby(['Delay_category1', 'Delay_category2']).cumcount(ascending=False) + 1
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   Id  Name Delay_category1 Delay_category2  Consecutive_Count
0   1  xyz1          [0-10]         [11-20]                  3
1   2  xyz2          [0-10]         [11-20]                  2
2   3  xyz3          [0-10]         [11-20]                  1
3   4  xyz4         [30-60]          [0-10]                  1
```